# How to pass argument / variable / parameter to symfony 2.4 form theme?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am customizing my form theme and wonder if there is a way to pass a variable into the theme?

e.g. i customize the label_block and want to add a class to all labelfields, instead of doing this one by one. What would be a way to pass a variable into the form theme?

Comment: Hi. Do you find an answer to your question ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass argument through the formBuilder.

Here is an example with a parameter `autocompleteJsonWsUrl`passed to the collection_widget

in the thig view !

```
{% form_theme form 'AppBundle:Form:collection.html.twig' %}
{{ form(form) }}
```

in the the collection twig view

```
{% block collection_widget %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var $autocompleteJsonWsUrl = "{{ attr['autocompleteJsonWsUrl'] }}";
        var $collectionHtmlId = "{{ form.vars.id }}";
        initialiseCollectionFieldProcessing($collectionHtmlId,$autocompleteJsonWsUrl);
    });
</script>
<div id="{{ form.vars.id }}" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.vars.prototype)|escape }}">
    <ul class="collection">
    {% for child in form %}
        <li>{{ form_row(child) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

in the form builder :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
$contributersAutocompleteJsonWsUrl = $options['contributersAutocompleteJsonWsUrl'];
$builder->add('contributers','collection',array(
            'label'                 => 'request.form.contributers', 
            'type'                  => 'userSelector',
            'allow_add'             => true,
            'allow_delete'          => true,
            'by_reference'          => false,
            'required'              => false,
            'error_bubbling'        => false,
            'attr'                  => array('autocompleteJsonWsUrl' => $contributersAutocompleteJsonWsUrl ),
            'options'               => array(
                'label' => false,
                'invalid_message' => 'request.contributer.404')));
$builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'request.form.add.submit'));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
    $defaults = array(
        'data_class'            => 'AppBundle\Entity\Request',
        'intention'             => 'request',
        'translation_domain'    => 'request',
        'contributersAutocompleteJsonWsUrl' => ''
    );
    $resolver->setDefaults($defaults);
}
```

In the controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm(new $formName,$object, array('contributersAutocompleteJsonWsUrl' => $contributersAutocompleteJsonWsUrl));
```